# Perl + Possibility of multiple ALRM signals

Tags: perl, signals

**Scenario :** Parent process shall spawn N worker children to load data to stage tables , and Parent frequently (every 15mins) invokes a stored procedure to move date from stage -> core

**Idea :** planning to setup an **'$SIG{ALRM}'** handler for every 15mins and invoke the stored procedure in the signal handler.

Seek suggestions if it's a good idea to setup Signal handlers to invoke a stored procedure whose execution time should be ~5mins , wondering what happens if the stored procedure runs beyond 15mins when another ALRM signal goes off.

Would this second signal get

- queued to be handled later
- gets lost completely
- invoke another handler and stored procedure instance, while the previous handler is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking what happens if you have

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
   alarm(15*60);
   call_stored_proc();
};

alarm(15*60);
```

and `call_stored_proc` takes longer than 15 minutes. Why didn't you just try it?

```
perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );

   my $slow = 2;
   my $done = 0;

   sub call_stored_proc {
      say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "call_stored_proc", "enter";
      sleep($slow ? 8 : 2);
      say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "call_stored_proc", "leave";
      $done = 1 if !$slow;
      --$slow;
   }

   $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
      say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "SIGALRM hander", "enter";
      say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "SIGALRM hander", "alarm set for ".(time+5);
      alarm(5);
      call_stored_proc();
      say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "SIGALRM hander", "leave";
   };

   say sprintf "[%s] %s: %s", time, "[root]", "alarm set for ".(time+5);
   alarm(5);
   sleep(1) while !$done;
'
```

Output:

```
[1474490009] [root]: alarm set for 1474490014
[1474490014] SIGALRM hander: enter
[1474490014] SIGALRM hander: alarm set for 1474490019
[1474490014] call_stored_proc: enter
[1474490022] call_stored_proc: leave
[1474490022] SIGALRM hander: leave
[1474490022] SIGALRM hander: enter
[1474490022] SIGALRM hander: alarm set for 1474490027
[1474490022] call_stored_proc: enter
[1474490030] call_stored_proc: leave
[1474490030] SIGALRM hander: leave
[1474490031] SIGALRM hander: enter
[1474490031] SIGALRM hander: alarm set for 1474490036
[1474490031] call_stored_proc: enter
[1474490033] call_stored_proc: leave
[1474490033] SIGALRM hander: leave
```

As you can see, `call_stored_proc` isn't interrupted. SIGALRM is suppressed until the SIGALRM handler returns.

Comment: Note that you could surely unmask SIGALRM if you wanted a different result.